Determining the multiplier in limits for spotting Outliers
I want to determine the chance of having above-the-expected sales orders for products, then i could use this (my gut feeling and other business analysis) to determine if i should (or not) keep safety stock for products with frequent upper outlier sales orders.
A very brief explanation: If product A has consistently presented over X% of sales above the upper limit i will have a safety stock for it (which will be determined in another analysis afterwards. (I'm using Excel)
Problems:

The common approach (using IQR * multiplier) is looking kinda off to me, i have +or- 14% of my entries that look normal but are considered outliers, but i'm willing to accept that
the other issue is, if i use SD (standard deviation) instead of the IQR method, my upper and lower limits increase dramatically
and the major issue is, how do i determine the multiplier? is there any factor/index i can add to the IQR or the SD methods to determine my multiplier? this way i could use Solver to help me or wtv

My sample using IQR

My Sample using IQR (sorted)

I really wouldn't mind patiently looking at this and using my feeling to determine the multiplier, but i actually want to apply this to other products i work with (and i have around 3500 SKUs),m.

I think you are making a mistake by setting this as a yes/no problem. Rather than "should I keep excess stock?" I think a better question is "How much stock should I keep?"
This will depend on many factors, certainly including

the cost of keeping stock
the speed with which you can get it
the urgency with which your customers need it.
the distribution of demand

Your sample data does not have any extreme outliers. In fact, it might not have any outliers at all, depending on your definition. It's just that demand does not seem to be normally distributed.
And there is no generally agreed upon definition - the best definition depends on context.
